# OpenShift: Wildfly takes most of the space in 1G, what to do?

Tags: java, openshift, wildfly

I signed up for `OpenShift` and created an `WildFly`, `Java 7` based app, when I deploy I see

```
remote: target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/common-core/main/jboss-common-core-2.2.22.GA.jar
remote: stderr: rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes to socket [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
remote: rsync: write failed on "/var/lib/openshift/53cc3d974382ec1f72000304/app-deployments/2014-07-20_18-21-00.502/repo/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/common-core/main/jboss-common-core-2.2.22.GA.jar": Disk quota exceeded (122)
remote: rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(301) [receiver=3.0.6]
remote: rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (17468 bytes received so far) [sender]
remote: rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
remote: 
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option
```

Then I log into machine and see what's taking up so much space, I realized that `wildfly` itself is eating up all of it

```
 du -h * | sort -rh | head -50
592M    wildfly
317M    wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05
317M    wildfly/usr/lib/jvm
317M    wildfly/usr/lib
317M    wildfly/usr
166M    wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/jre
165M    wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib
147M    app-root/runtime/repo/target
147M    app-root/runtime/repo
147M    app-root/runtime
147M    app-root
136M    wildfly/versions/8
136M    wildfly/versions
135M    app-root/runtime/repo/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final
120M    app-deployments/2014-07-20_18-21-00.502/repo/target
120M    app-deployments/2014-07-20_18-21-00.502/repo
120M    app-deployments/2014-07-20_18-21-00.502
120M    app-deployments
118M    wildfly/versions/8/modules
118M    wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/lib
118M    wildfly/modules
116M    wildfly/versions/8/modules/system/layers/base
116M    wildfly/versions/8/modules/system/layers
116M    wildfly/versions/8/modules/system
116M    wildfly/modules/system/layers/base
116M    wildfly/modules/system/layers
116M    wildfly/modules/system
116M    app-root/runtime/repo/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base
116M    app-root/runtime/repo/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers
116M    app-root/runtime/repo/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system
116M    app-root/runtime/repo/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules
107M    app-deployments/2014-07-20_18-21-00.502/repo/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final
95M wildfly/versions/8/modules/system/layers/base/org
95M wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org
95M app-root/runtime/repo/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org
90M app-deployments/2014-07-20_18-21-00.502/repo/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base
90M app-deployments/2014-07-20_18-21-00.502/repo/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers
90M app-deployments/2014-07-20_18-21-00.502/repo/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system
90M app-deployments/2014-07-20_18-21-00.502/repo/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules
68M app-deployments/2014-07-20_18-21-00.502/repo/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org
59M wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/i386
49M wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/lib/missioncontrol
43M wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/lib/missioncontrol/plugins
37M wildfly/versions/8/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss
37M wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss
37M app-root/runtime/repo/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss
32M wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/lib/visualvm
26M wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/ext
21M wildfly/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/lib/visualvm/platform
21M app-deployments/2014-07-20_18-21-00.502/repo/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss
```

How can I resolve this issue? Is wildfly not suitable for free plans?

Comment: Perhaps you don't need a copy of JDK under wildfly.  Can you use a version already available on the system?  Or can you get more than 1 GB (which isn't very much)

Answer (score 0):

If you did a DIY cartridge and then loaded wildfly on your own, then you're right language and framework libraries are going to consume part of your quota.

**EDIT**
If you use the wildfly quickstart located here https://www.openshift.com/quickstarts/wildfly-I will also use some of your quota. I launched a quick example and got the following

```
\> ls
app-deployments  app-root  git  wildfly

\> quota -s
Disk quotas for user 53cebb8c5973caacc500017c (uid 1317): 
Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
/dev/mapper/EBSStore01-user_home01 
             593M       0   1024M            5676       0   80000
```

That being said, its probably best to sign up for the bronze plan and add more storage ($1 per GB, per month) for larger java applications.

Comment: That quota command appears to show that 58% of the quota has already been used, just by deploying the quickstart.  I deployed a 102MB war file using the WildFly 8 quickstart, and got a warning during deployment that I was using 92% of quota.

Comment: Looks like you are correct, I was looking at the wrong number when I posting my answer. The quickstart looks to consume 593M of space upon default deployment. I'll adjust my answer.